# Why would a control's load event still be called when the parent page has an outputcache directive?

Tags: .net, asp.net, outputcache, webformsmvp

I have a page with a user control on it.  If I put this outputcache directive on the control, the load event on the control doesn't fire

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="3600" VaryByParam="id" %>
```

But if I put the same directive on the page that the control is on, the load event does fire.  Why would the behaviour be different? We're using the WebFormsMVP framework.

Answer (score 0):

That definitely should not happen with standard aspx/ascx pages, so I'm going to guess it's something specific to WebFormsMVP.

I'm not too familiar with WebFormsMVP, but are you sure that the OutputCache directive works at all in there? e.g. forget the user control, and simply write out <%= DateTime.Now %> from the page itself. If you don't get any caching behavior, then you've taken the user control part out of the equation.

Not a full answer, but possibly a step forward :)